# Getting boundingClientRect for a clipped element

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to get a boundingClientRect of an SVGElement which has been clipped - using this information, i want to position HTML elements on top of the SVG element.

My SVG looks like this (simplified, the original one has both multiple cascading viewports and multiple cascading transforms):

```
<svg width="96" height="80">
  <clippath id="clip">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 96 0 L 96 80 L 0 80 Z"/>
  </clippath>
  <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
    <image x="0" y="-8" width="96" height="96" xlink:href="…" transform="…"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I want to position HTML elements on top of the SVGGElement. To do this, i get the boundingClientRect of

- the HTMLElement being positioned
- the HTMLElements parent
- Element ? that allows me to get the boundingClientRect of the SVGGelement with Clipping applied

In Chrome, this works by getting the boundingClientRect of the SVGPathElement. In Opera and Firefox, the resulting clientRect has width and height 0 (probably because the path element isn't displayed). The boundingClientRect of the SVGGelement itself gets its dimensions from contained SVGImageElement regardless of the clip-path applied.

I tried referencing the SVGPathElement through a SVGUseElement and getting the boundingClientRect of that - which seemed to work.

Is it really necessary to introduce another DOM element that is set to visibility hidden and pointer-events: none or does anyone know a better solution?